# Push from Table View to Detail View

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I'm developing an application that imports data from a csv file and is displayed in a Table view. I have no problem in displaying the data in the table view but after that I'd like to be able to show the data of each row displayed in a detail view. I have implemented the following code but when running the application, it doesn't seem to respond to the push method.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    CompanyDetailViewController *dvController = [[CompanyDetailViewController alloc] 
                                                 initWithNibName:@"ViewController" 
                                                 bundle: nil];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];

    Company *p = (Company *)[self.importedRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"You've selected %@ and the telephone number is %@ address %@", p.companyName, p.companyTelephone, p.companyAddress);
}
```

As you can see I also created the NSLog to check if the application is reading the block and  it seems to print the data correctly in the log panel.

I hope someone can help on what to consider to make this work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code only and check it will work for you or not.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     str=[arrayName objectAtindex:indexpath.row];

      ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

}
```

In .h assign the NSString *str globally and use in another view this str have all the what you want.

Comment: I tried your code and created str as a global NSString. Maybe it is a very noob question but what's the arrayName suposed to do? I receive a compilation error because it is an undeclared identifier.

Comment: You have something in your cell or you pass some array in your table that array only you pass here.

Comment: What I have in my cell are the contents of some variables created in company.h and company.m.
I referred with a pointer but not sure of how it should work.

Company *p = (Company *)[self.importedRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

It's a very novice question but it would really help me to know how to implement it.